# Uniform continuity of sequence of function

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Is $\dfrac{x^{1.9}}{(x^2 + n^4)}$ uniformly convergent to 0 given that $x>0$

To prove it’s indeed uniformly convergence, how do I find its maximum?

i only got x^1.9/(x^2+n^4) <= x^1.9/n^4. have no clue how to show x^1.9/n^4 goes to zero as n goes to infinity

Comment: Us the fact that it is bounded by $\min \{ \frac 1 {x^{0.1}}, \frac {x^{1.9}} {n^{4}}\}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: since x^1.9/n^4 is unbounded, does it mean it's not uniformly convergent?